# Call a Javascript function from jstl foreach

Tags: javascript, spring, forms, jsp, dom-events

I am iterating over a list in JSTL to show its records. There is `onclick="editList()"` event on each `<form:label`. I want to send both `${item.id}` and `${item.number}` in the `editList()` function parameters if any of them is clicked. How can I send these parameters.

```
<c:forEach var='item' items='${rule.list}' varStatus="itemsRow">
 <tr>
    <form:label path="list[${itemsRow.index}].id" onclick="editList()">
     ${item.id}
    </form:label>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <form:label path="list[${itemsRow.index}].number" onclick="editList()">
     ${item.number}
    </form:label>
 </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onclick="editList('${item.id}', '${item.number}')"
```